# What is correct syntax if query statment include '?

Tags: sqlite

I'm executing this query statement using SQLite Manager firefox plugin.

The query statement is:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."bibles" ("scripture","chapter","verse","content")
VALUES("NINGPAWT NINGHPANG"," 22","2 "," Shaloi Karai Kasang gaw, \'Nang tsawra ai, na shadang sha shingtai Isak hpe woi nna Moria ga de sa wa su; ngai nang hpe madun na ra de ai bum hta shi hpe wan nat hkungga di nna nawng e,\" ngu wu ai. ");
```

SQLite Manager Alert is:

```
SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: INSERT INTO "main"."bibles" ("scripture","chapter","verse","content")
  VALUES("NINGPAWT NINGHPANG"," 22","2 "," Shaloi Karai Kasang gaw, \'Nang tsawra ai, na shadang sha shingtai Isak hpe woi nna Moria ga de sa wa su; ngai nang hpe madun na ra de ai bum hta shi hpe wan nat hkungga di nna nawng e,\" ngu wu ai. ");
[ near "ngu": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

Isn't my query statement correct?
What's the correct statement?

Comment: Try changing *awng e,\" ngu wu* in *awng e,\' ngu wu*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has different quote escaping.

Dont escape `'` like `\'` but like `''`

Dont escape `"` like `\"` but like `""`

Comment: Thanks u very much. This is the answer. Can't accept your answer waiting for 4 mins. Thankssssssssssssssssssssssss @Zaffy